# Replacement for SVG

Tags: javascript, graphics, svg, 2d

My project is using SVG and there is a plan to move out of SVG and replace the existing functionality with suitable replacement.
My current SVG apps does following things,
1. Exposes the object(SVG shapes) relations or dependency in screen.
  When there are two dependent shapes (say rect1 and rect2), we draw a line from rect1 to react2 to say that they are dependent.
2. Triggers javascript functions when we fire certain events (click or mouse over) on shapes.

Is there any alternatives to replace the SVG and simply the drawing process?
I am thinking to store the shapes information in database and auto generate the shapes in UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to replace SVG? SVG is by far the best technology for this.

Answer (score -1):

What about using canvas from HTML 5. Consider client browsers version when decide to use canvas.

Comment: It seems that developers needs to do more to manage the events on shapes with canvas.

Comment: The SVG scene graph enables event handlers to be associated with objects, so a rectangle may respond to an onClick event. To get the same functionality with canvas, one must manually match the coordinates of the mouse click with the coordinates of the drawn rectangle to determine whether it was clicked. [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element#Canvas_versus_Scalable_Vector_Graphics_.28SVG.29)

Comment: Yes thats pitty. But you can create base objects which can handle these events, and inherit all ur objects from base. This way it simplifies the event handling.